# Approximation of Jordan curves

Tags: real-analysis, plane-curves

Let $J$ be a Jordan curve in the plane, looked  upon as the homeomorphic image of the unit circle T. Suppose that for some  $\epsilon>0$ there is another
Jordan curve $K$ such that $K\subseteq V:= \{z: dist(z, J)< \epsilon\}$,
the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $J$.
Do there exist parametrizations $j:T\to J$ of $J$ and $k:T\to K$ of $K$ such that  $|j(\xi)-k(\xi)|< C \epsilon$ for every $\xi\in T$?

Comment: At a glance the answer appears to be "yes". Could you please add a bit of context: Did this come up in another mathematical problem you're working on (so a sketch would suffice), or is this, say, a homework problem (in which case it would help to know in what course, and what tools you have available)? Thank you. :)

Comment: I am a lecturer and wanted to know whether these two concepts of approximations in the realm of Jordan curves are the same. Level: Master1 (Europe).

Comment: As David Ullrich's examples show, my initial assessment was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Actually I think you sort of didn't ask the question you meant to ask; we give a trivial counterexample to the question as asked and then a not *quite* as trivial counterexample to the question I think you meant to ask.

First, let $J$ be the unit circle, and let $K$ be the circle of radius $\epsilon/2$ centered at the point $1$. Every point of $K$ is close to a point of $J$ but the conclusion clearly fails.

What seems like the right version of the question assumes that every point of $K$ is close to a point of $J$, *and* that every point of $J$ is close to a point of $K$. Counterexample to that version:

Let $J$ be the unit circle.
Choose a very small number $\delta>0$. Let $r=1-\delta$, $R=1+\delta$. Define $K$ like so: Start at $Re^{i\delta}$. Run along the circle $|z|=R$ counterclockwise to the point $R=Re^{2\pi i}$. Take a straight line from $R$ to $r$. Run along the circle $|z|=r$ clockwise to the point $re^{i\delta}$, and then take a straight line back to $Re^{i\delta}$.

---

**Edit** We may as well parametrize $J$ by $g(e^{it})=e^{it}$. So we need to show there is no homeomorphism $f:S^1\to K$ with $|f(e^{it})-e^{it}|<\delta$. The best way to see this is to convince yourself that it's obvious; $e^{it}$ would have to be mapped to two different points of $K$. The following proof is imo far from the best way to see it, but it's by far the easiest thing to write down with complete rigor:

If $|f(e^{it})-e^{it}|=|f(e^{it})-g(e^{it})|<\delta<1$ then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. So $f$ and $g$ have the same index, ie winding number, about the origin. Hence $0=1$.

Comment: Why the conclusion fails in the second case? If $f(e^{it})$ is a parametrisation of the curve $K$, then $|f(e^{it})-e^{it}|<2\delta$? Start with $t=0; f(1)=1+\delta$, then for $0<t<delta$ parametrize the small curve and arrive at $f(\delta)=(1+\delta)e^{i\delta}$; then continue with the parameter equal the angle.

Comment: What? If II understand your description correctly, you're mapping $e^{it}$ to two different points, one on $|z|=R$ and one on $|z|=r$! That's not a function. If the parametrization you have in mind does not have this property please write it down more carefully.

Comment: Hmm. Just to make it easier to write down our parametrizations, let's forget that $K$ is suppsoed to be a Jordan curve. Say $K'$ runs over the entire unit circle twice, once counterclockwise and once clockwise. Tell me how to parametriize $K'$ so $|f(e^{it}-e^{it}|$ remains small for every $t$.

Comment: @ray Note I added a formal proof to the answer...

Comment: okay; I ran through the circle with radius  r the wrong way...The argument with the homotopies is convincing. Could you please include the figure of the curve K? I don't know how to put jpg's. Th.

Comment: @ray I really don't see any need for a figure. You didn't have any trouble figuring out what curve I meant, did you? The description seems clear and not that complicated...